# Why we don't use UI Elements in Viewmodel in MVVM Viewmodel Pattern

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

I have some doubts in viewmodel pattern. My doubt is about, why we don't use UI elements in viewmodel. If we use UI elements in viewmodel what will happen like any performance issue?. Please give any suggestion.

Comment: This will almost certainly get flagged due to being too broad, but one very good reason keeping the view model and view separated is for testing. When all your logic is in the view model you can actually run your entire program without creating any graphical objects at all. This means you can mock entire sections of your code and insert them using dependency injection, which in turn means you can now write automated tests for all of your actual code. There are many, many other reasons for doing this....including the fact that it forces you to better structure your architecture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not use UIElements in ViewModels, since the MVVM principle defines UIElements to reside in the View. The correct placement of UIElements, is defined by John Gossman, in the article [Introduction to Model/View/ViewModel pattern for building WPF apps](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johngossman/2005/10/08/introduction-to-modelviewviewmodel-pattern-for-building-wpf-apps/):

> The View in Model/View/ViewModel consists of the visual elements, the buttons, windows, graphics and more complex controls of a GUI.

You do not use UIElements in the ViewModel of an MVVM application, for at least two reasons:

- When later porting the application to another UI framework, it is much easier if all UI related code is just in one module, namely the View. Porting would be much harder if UI code would be spread across the View and the ViewModel.
- Unit testing is much easier if all UI related code is just in the View.

The latter reason, of course, is the most important, for most developers. Josh Smith, the father of WPF-MVVM puts it like this in his article [Patterns - WPF Apps With The Model-View-ViewModel Design Pattern](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx?irgwc=1&OCID=AID681541_aff_7593_1243925&tduid=(ir_19GV53wpRxu6RAR1Xv1ohUhPUkjVrnTVC1LGxY0)(7593)(1243925)(TnL5HPStwNw-OgZwqWFRiiWU6Q5bVUv3NQ)()&irclickid=19GV53wpRxu6RAR1Xv1ohUhPUkjVrnTVC1LGxY0):

> If you can write unit tests for the ViewModel without creating any UI objects, you can also completely skin the ViewModel because it has no dependencies on specific visual elements.

UIElements are troublesome for unit tests, because WPF UIElements need a layout-measure-render loop for working correctly. In unit tests, however, you usually do not have such a loop.

Comment: Don't feed the pigeons.  _[Stance on answering “bad” questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions)_ and _[Should one advise on off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)_.  Also, _"by the creator of MVVM, John Gossman"_ - well no, it was Ken Cooper and Ted Peters. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel

Comment: @FrankM, Thank you very much for your clear explanation.

Comment: @MickyD I do not think that this is a bad question. It is precise enough and you can give an objective answer.

Comment: @user10092067 There is one more important point. A UIElement can not have more than one parent element. Imagine e.g. a collection of view model items that are shown in two or more ItemsControls at the same time. That won't work with UIElement items. For the point of later porting an application to a different framework: if this is takes seriously, you must avoid using *any* type from the UI framework in the view model, not only UIElements, e.g. ImageSource, Geometry, Brush.

Comment: @Clemens, Thanks for your explanation.