# How-to: MVVM ViewModel with properties that update UI elements in willSet/didSet

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453137/why-we-dont-use-ui-elements-in-viewmodel-in-mvvm-viewmodel-pattern), it's not the way to go but how do I go about handling this so I can update UI elements when said property is update.

This would easily be achieved in SwiftUI using `@Published`

```
    var exchangeRate: Double = 1.0 {
    willSet {
        guard let doubleFormattedValue = Double.format(newValue, numberStyle: .decimal, decimalPlaces: 6) else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.rateLabel.text = String(doubleFormattedValue) + " " + self.fromCurrencyTextField.currency.rawValue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: MVVM is not a particularly good fit with UIKit as it does not have an inherent binding framework like SwiftUI.  You can use Combine with subscribers in your UIViewController and publishers in your view model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the suggestion of @Paulw11 and [this tutorial](https://betterprogramming.pub/uikit-mvvm-combine-912c80c02262), I was able to implement the following:

```
private var viewModel: CurrencyConverterViewModel = CurrencyConverterViewModel()
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

private func configureBinding() {

    viewModel.$exchangeRate
        .sink { [weak self] exchangeRate in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            // UI changes go here
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
}
```

Comment: Looks good to me. You may want to introduce a function `update(old: ViewState, new: ViewState)` which may also drill down to child view controllers. Problems which may arise here is that when you use animations, a subsequent update function may overlap with the animations from the previous update. A robust solution may be tricky for certain cases.

Answer (score 0):

ViewModel shouldn't have any inforamtion about the View you can use binding with change handler and escaping, this solution is without combine or rxswift or async await etc.

such as:

```
enum SampleViewModelChange {
    case didValueChanged
    case didError(Error)
    case didEverythingYouWant
}

final class SampleViewModel {
    var sampleChangeHandler: ((SampleViewModelChange) -> Void)?

   var exchangeRate: Double = 1.0 {
       willSet {
          emitSample(.didValueChanged)
       }
       didSet {
          emitSample(.didEverythingYouWant)
       }
   }

    func emitSample(_ change: SampleViewModelChange) {
        sampleChangeHandler?(change)
    }
}
```

in your view you can have:

```
class SampleVC: UIViewController {
    var viewModel: SampleViewModel


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        bindViewModel()
    }


    func bindViewModel() {
        viewModel.sampleChangeHandler = { [weak self] change in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            switch change {
            case .didValueChanged:
                debugPrint(didValueChanged)
                self.rateLabel.text = String(doubleFormattedValue) + " " + self.fromCurrencyTextField.currency.rawValue
     
            case .didError(let error):
                debugPrint(error)
            case .didEverythingYouWant:
                debugPrint(EverythingYouWant such as reload table or every thing you want)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

To me MVVM does not depend on UIView or SwiftUI or Snappkit, you can use MVVM with every UI that you want. this is a general Architecture.